# BottomAppBar navigation items are not clickable because of NestedScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout

My app bar is located below my scroll view and therefore the items are not clickable

My scroll view should stop just above my BottomAppBar

how to do that ?

And how to make the BottomAppBar always visible

Useless text for my post to pass, very restrictive this rule

The story of a cat who wanted to eat the dog's bowl.

I hope there is enough unnecessary text

[image]

Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/bottomAppBar"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomAppBar.Colored"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_show_bottom"
        app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_action_home_blank" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/contentScroll"
        layout="@layout/content_scrolling" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/btnAddClean"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/bottomAppBar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_action_clean" />


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Content scrolled

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/fragment_avaloir_show">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rueTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:text="Rue des jolis bois " />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/avaloirImageView"
            android:layout_width="263dp"
            android:layout_height="350dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/content_description"
            android:src="@drawable/aval2"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/rueTextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/coordinatesTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/avaloirImageView"
            tools:text="50.235621, 5.23658" />

        <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
            android:id="@+id/mapView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="350dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/coordinatesTextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titreDatesNettoyageTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:text="@string/title_dates_nettoyage"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mapView" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/dividerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/titreDatesNettoyageTextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/datesTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/dividerView"
            tools:text="10 avril 2019" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titreCommentairesTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:text="@string/title_commentaires"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/datesTextView" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/commentDividerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/titreCommentairesTextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/commentairesTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/commentDividerView"
            tools:text="Il est cassé il faut le remplacer" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

finally I added a linearLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/contentScroll"
                layout="@layout/content_scrolling" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/bottomAppBar"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomAppBar.Colored"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_show_bottom"
        app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_action_home_blank" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/btnAddClean"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/bottomAppBar"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_action_clean" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rueTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="Rue des jolis bois " />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/avaloirImageView"
        android:layout_width="263dp"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/content_description"
        android:src="@drawable/aval2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/rueTextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/coordinatesTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/avaloirImageView"
        tools:text="50.235621, 5.23658" />

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/coordinatesTextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titreDatesNettoyageTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="@string/title_dates_nettoyage"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mapView" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/dividerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/titreDatesNettoyageTextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/datesTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/dividerView"
        tools:text="10 avril 2019" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titreCommentairesTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="@string/title_commentaires"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/datesTextView" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/commentDividerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/titreCommentairesTextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/commentairesTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/commentDividerView"
        tools:text="Il est cassé il faut le remplacer" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```